# Jenkins: how to remove the surrounding stage over parallel stages in the Web UI?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I have the following declarative pipeline in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  ...

  stage('Deployment') {
    parallel {
      stage('Deployment:CI') {
        ...                     
      }
      stage('Deployment:Test') {
        ...                     
      }
      stage('Deployment:Production') {
        ...                     
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

And in the web interface of jenkins it looks like as below:

[image]

As you can see there is a (dummy) stage in the GUI, i.e. Deployment, which is only a surrounding stage and does nothing.
My question is: How could I get rid of this stage in the Web interface and still have the parallel stages?

Comment: I don't think you can get directly rid of it but you could use Blue Ocean where this is shown a lot prettier and your "surrounding stage" is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I installed [Blue Ocean](https://www.jenkins.io/projects/blueocean/) as a plugin in my Jenkins. Here's an screen shot of what I actually needed:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you declare stages in jenkinsfile - it couldn't be hide in standart interface while pipeline execution.